# Redirect issues with non www .htaccess

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

This has been driving me nuts for the longest time. I don't know if its something cached somewhere or what. But my rewrite for non www to www does not seem to be working.

Two bits of code here to examin.

The code below does not take example.com and redirect it to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

I also have a rule for looking up member info which is the last line so george.example.com does get redirected to [www.example.com/member-photos/1](http://www.example.com/member-photos/1)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/member-photos/${liusers:%1|0} [L]
```

Now this bit of code does redirect as long as i leave out my member lookup rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/member-photos/${liusers:%1|0} [L]
```

If I uncomment the

```
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/member-photos/${liusers:%1|0} [L]
```

When you go to example.com it asumes you are trying to lookup a member with the Rewrite rule and the page fails.

So, my dilema is to send non www to www while still beuing able to use the db lookup rule which starts with a membername,example.com

Any tips or eye openers would be really appreciated.

I hope the following is a bit more clear in what my goal is.

I have thousands of users on my website and they all have a gallery of photos.

I would like non www to get sent to www.

`example.com  --->  www.example.com`

That rule is simple with the following unless there is a better way or I am doing something wrong.

```
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

OR even this variation works

```
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
```

Now, the other rule is for a db lookup of a member.

for example

`foobar.example.com` Would take the foobar part of the url, lookup a userid for username foobar. If found would then redirect to `www.example.com/member-photos/userid` where userid is a number

I think the problem is a catch all at the beginning of the URL which conflicts with the non www rule. I just don't know

Comment: What member are you _expecting_ to be looked up in the second rule? Or what value are you expecting to be in the redirect target in this case? (From the look of that rule I would expect `https://www.example.com/member-photos/0` - is that not happening? Is that not correct?)

Comment: I am using module mod_dbl with database parameter defined.  So, when the rule is processed, it could be any of several thousand members.  Itjust takes the member name in front of .example.com looks up the userid for that member then redirects to the member page. Here is a real example from another site with the same db lookup rule stroop.zeissimages.com  if you use https it wil give a warning because letsencrypt does not hand subs. so its a hack.

Comment: Yes, but what are you expecting to happen for `example.com` (the domain apex and which you are targeting in the second rule)? Which is the rule that appears to be causing concern. I'm not sure why you are trying to perform a lookup here? Are you suggesting there is no redirect at all when including the "member lookup" rule (which seems odd)? But I'm not sure what you mean by "it asumes you are trying to lookup a member with the Rewrite rule"?

Comment: ok. let me see if i can explain it better by amending the question since there is not enough space in comments. And thanks for looking !